# Diffie Hellman+AES on C# to Android data encryption

Tags: c#, android, aes, diffie-hellman

Anyone know how to implement data exchange between Android app and c# Webservice and vice versa by using DH key exchange with AES encryption. Because writing hard-coded encryption key in Andoird is not secure that anyone can do re-engineering and collect the private hard-coded key..

Comment: Use TLS. You can have TLS use a cipher suite that uses DH and AES, but don't try to roll the protocol yourself.

Comment: Do you have any reference link..